# Spring Batch support for OpenEdge database?

Tags: spring-batch, openedge, progress-db

The company I work for has to support different databases and one of them is OpenEdge, which I never used before. We have a project using Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA and Spring Batch.

We added a few custom classes to make Spring Batch work with OpenEdge but we are having DB locking issues whereas it works fine for MS SQL Server and Oracle. Anybody using Spring Batch with OpenEdge DB? Does anybody know if Spring Batch will ever support OpenEdge out-of-the-box?

I am looking for a job repository implementation backed by OpenEdge and recommendations regarding how to use it with OpenEdge because I have DB locking issues. One of the locking errors I get is:

```java
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT STEP_EXECUTION_ID, STEP_NAME, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION from DM_SB_STEP_EXECUTION where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? order by STEP_EXECUTION_ID]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [-210015]; [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Failure getting record lock on a record from table PUB.DM_SB_STEP_EXECUTION.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Failure getting record lock on a record from table PUB.DM_SB_STEP_EXECUTION.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:756) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao.addStepExecutions(JdbcStepExecutionDao.java:299) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.precisionsoftware.dem.batch.config.PrecisionSimpleJobRepository.getStepExecutionCount(PrecisionSimpleJobRepository.java:261) ~[classes!/:7.1.0-0]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.shouldStart(SimpleStepHandler.java:222) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:394) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.precisionsoftware.dem.batch.config.PrecisionJobLauncher$1.run(PrecisionJobLauncher.java:185) [classes!/:7.1.0-0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Failure getting record lock on a record from table PUB.DM_SB_STEP_EXECUTION.
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.client.dde.ah(Unknown Source) ~[openedge-11.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.client.dde.ag(Unknown Source) ~[openedge-11.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.dde.a(Unknown Source) ~[openedge-11.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddcq.aa(Unknown Source) ~[openedge-11.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.dddm.next(Unknown Source) ~[openedge-11.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

And below the code that creates the query that is causing issues:

```java
public int getStepExecutionCount(JobInstance jobInstance, String stepName) {
    int count = 0;
    List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExecutionDao.findJobExecutions(jobInstance);
    for (JobExecution jobExecution : jobExecutions) {
      stepExecutionDao.addStepExecutions(jobExecution);
      for (StepExecution stepExecution : jobExecution.getStepExecutions()) {
        if (stepName.equals(stepExecution.getStepName())) {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

Spring Batch tables prefix was changed to DM_SB_

Comment: Are you looking for item reader/writer support for OpenEdge or for a job repository implementation backed by OpenEdge (for job metadata)?

Comment: It seems like what you really need is some help with “dB locking issues”.  I suggest revising your question to describe those issues, show the code that brings them out and include any error messages associated with them.

Comment: ok, it looks like you edited the question saying that you are looking for a job repository implementation backed by OpenEdge. Spring Batch does not provide support for this database OOTB.

Comment: thanks @MahmoudBenHassine see below what I ended up doing.

Comment: @TomBascom I updated the question so you could see more details of the code that generates the query and the generated error. Any suggestion regarding how to avoid locks with OpenEdge?

Answer (score 1):

The performance of OpenEdge DB seems to be very poor when counting and sorting.

I have ended up changing the transactional behaviour for the Spring Batch metadata and it does not fail but do not think that is the best solution. See the XML I am importing using @ImportResource annotation.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<!-- Transactional configuration for Spring Batch -->
<tx:advice id="myTxAdvice" transaction-manager="springBatchTransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="create*" read-only="false" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
        <tx:method name="getLastJobExecution*" read-only="false" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" read-only="false" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="add*" read-only="false" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="true" isolation="READ_UNCOMMITTED" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.company.dem.batch.config.*Repository+.*(..))" advice-ref="myTxAdvice"/>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: If all you are doing is counting why aren't you using a read-only connection or a no-lock query?

Comment: That is what it does now. The XML chunk from above is to change the transactional behaviour of the Spring Batch framework so queries are execute using read only mode and READ_UNCOMMITTED. What I do not understand is the reason I was getting a lock error when executing the following query providing fields from the where and order by are indexed `SELECT * from DM_SB_STEP_EXECUTION where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? order by STEP_EXECUTION_ID`

Comment: If you are getting lock errors then I would have to think that your connection is not a read-only connection.  The fields being part of an index (or not) doesn't affect whether or not locks are needed but it could impact how many locks have to be taken.

Comment: Poor performance (that doesn't involve locks, which I think you are saying is the case with the query in this answer) could be from a poor query plan.  The SQL engine needs up to date statistics in order to optimize queries.  It could just be that your DBA has not run "update statistics" recently.